# Trouble Calculating Bounding Boxes Splits for Cascading Shadow Mapping

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

As the title suggests I've been trying to implement cascading shadow mapping however I can't seem to calculate the splits correctly. I found [this](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial49/tutorial49.html) tutorial which explained it quite well and even provided code samples but I must be doing something wrong when it comes to calculating the bounding box for each cascade. If I hard-code the light's orthographic projection `lightProj = glm::ortho(-50.f, 50.f, -50.f, 50.f, 0.1f, 120.f);`(basically having each cascade span the entire scene) it works (obviously each cascade would have poor resolution). Here is the code:

```
void calcCascadeProjections() {
    glm::vec3 sunPos(0, 50, -50);
    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(cam.Position, cam.Position + cam.Front, cam.Up); 
    glm::mat4 viewInverse = glm::inverse(view);
    glm::mat4 lightView = glm::lookAt(sunPos, glm::vec3(0), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

    float ar = (float)SCR_HEIGHT / (float)SCR_WIDTH;
    float tanHalfHFov = tan(glm::radians(45.0f / 2.0f));
    float tanHalfVFov = tan(glm::radians((45.0f * ar) / 2.0f));  

    //tan of half the FOV = x of frustum corner/ z of frustum corner
    //since we know the z of each cascade (where each cascade ends)
    //then x of frustum = tan of half FOV * z of frustum corner
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < CSM_CASCADES; i++) {
        float xn = cascadeEnds[i] * tanHalfHFov;
        float xf = cascadeEnds[i + 1] * tanHalfHFov;
        float yn = cascadeEnds[i] * tanHalfVFov;
        float yf = cascadeEnds[i + 1] * tanHalfVFov;

        glm::vec4 frustumCorners[8] = {
            glm::vec4(xn, yn, cascadeEnds[i], 1.0),
            glm::vec4(-xn, yn, cascadeEnds[i], 1.0),
            glm::vec4(xn, -yn, cascadeEnds[i], 1.0),
            glm::vec4(-xn, -yn, cascadeEnds[i], 1.0),

            glm::vec4(xf, yf, cascadeEnds[i + 1], 1.0),
            glm::vec4(-xf, yf, cascadeEnds[i + 1], 1.0),
            glm::vec4(xf, -yf, cascadeEnds[i + 1], 1.0),
            glm::vec4(-xf, -yf, cascadeEnds[i + 1], 1.0)        
        };
        glm::vec4 frustumCornersLight[8];
        float minx = FLT_MAX;
        float maxx = FLT_MIN;
        float miny = FLT_MAX;
        float maxy = FLT_MIN;
        float minz = FLT_MAX;
        float maxz = FLT_MIN;

        for (uint8_t j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            //to get the position in view space multiply view matrix * position vector in world space
            //so multiplying the inverse view matrix to both sides should result in the position vector in world space
            glm::vec4 world = viewInverse * frustumCorners[j];
            frustumCornersLight[j] = lightView * world;

            minx = MIN(minx, frustumCornersLight[j].x);
            maxx = MAX(maxx, frustumCornersLight[j].x);
            miny = MIN(miny, frustumCornersLight[j].y);
            maxy = MAX(maxy, frustumCornersLight[j].y);
            minz = MIN(minz, frustumCornersLight[j].z);
            maxz = MAX(maxz, frustumCornersLight[j].z);
            //turn the light frustum into a bounding box which is then passed to glm::ortho()

        }
        cascadeBoundingBoxes[i]l = minx; //left
        cascadeBoundingBoxes[i]r = maxx; //right
        cascadeBoundingBoxes[i]b = miny; //bottom
        cascadeBoundingBoxes[i]t = maxy; //top
        cascadeBoundingBoxes[i]n = minz; //near
        cascadeBoundingBoxes[i]f = maxz; //far
        printf("Box %d: %f %f %f %f %f %f \n", i, minx, maxx, miny, maxy, minz, maxz);
    }
}
```

The cascade ends array I set beforehand with `cascadeEnds[0]` being the near depth (0.1f) and `cascadeEnds[4]` being the far depth (120.f) of the original light projection.

After calculating these bounding boxes, for each cascade I would use the bounding box to set the light's orthographic projection matrix

```
            for (int i = 0; i < CSM_CASCADES; i++) {
                bindCSMforWriting(i); //selects the correct depth texture
                lightProj = glm::ortho(cascadeBoundingBoxes[i]l, cascadeBoundingBoxes[i]r, cascadeBoundingBoxes[i]b, cascadeBoundingBoxes[i]t, cascadeBoundingBoxes[i]n, cascadeBoundingBoxes[i]f);
                lightSpaceTransform = lightProj * lightView;

                USE_SHADER(shader->id);
                std::string uniform = "lightSpaceMatrix[" + std::to_string(i) + "]";
                SHADER_SET_MAT4(shader->id, uniform.c_str(), lightSpaceTransform);
                USE_SHADER(depthShader);

                SHADER_SET_MAT4(depthShader, "lightSpaceMat", lightSpaceTransform);
                glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTextures[i]);
                if (graphics != 0) {
                    //if shadows are enabled
                    scene->renderScene(depthShader, true, cam, deltaTime, graphics);
                }
            }
```

When the bounding boxes are calculated, I get very strange values. What I notice is the far depth of each cascade is always 0. With some bounding boxes the bottom of it will be above the highest point on the scene etc. I'm not sure what I'm not understanding so all help will be appreciated!

Comment: I think this is a very good case for using a debugger to see some values. Specially those of `cascadeEnds` and `FLT_MXX`. BTW, `cascadeEnds` used in `frustumCorners` should be negative values, they are view coordinates, right?

Comment: @Ripi2 Thank you I will take up on your suggestion. The issue is most likely coming from my misunderstanding of view space: Isn't it just world space but the viewer is the origin of that space? Sorry if this seems like a dumb question but why should the `cascadeEnds` be negative values?